# Pentaho Spoon Text File Output Additional Information Header

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am using the Text File Output step to create a CSV file, however i need to insert some additional rows of information at the top of the file. I have been able to have another transform output this data in a previous job step, however when doing so prevents me from outputting column headers in the appended csv output.

The end result I am looking for would look something like this:

EXTRACT TYPE: XYZ

DATE: 20110520

FIRST NAME,LAST NAME,AMOUNT

charlie, chaplain, 2345

someone, else, 1234

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can output the text file without header option. Check the KTR file - I attach the links below.

Here's the : http://pentaho.phi-integration.com/kettle/kettle-files/csv_header_solution.ktr and the sample source CSV file : http://pentaho.phi-integration.com/kettle/kettle-files/source.csv.

Hope this help.

Comment: dino76 - that worked a treat! Thanks for taking the time to come up with the solution. Seems i'm unable to up-vote your answer due to myself having low rep :(

Comment: Hi.. it's ok. Glad that it helps !