# How to add header row in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am using pentaho version pdi-ce-5.4.0.1-130. I am out puting my rows using Text output and have a loop that inserts row into text file based on number of years(2008-2015). I have checked both the append and header check boxes.

What i cant understand is why i cant see the header columns once the text files is created and after the rows have been inserted? is there anyway around this so that i can add header rows after i have created the file?

I have been to pentaho forum and it mentions that they have fixed the header issues.

Comment: Solution looks to me very simple. Just read again headless file and dump it into new csv file with headers.

Comment: @simar, i will give it a try. thanks!

Comment: You can see there here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072223/pentaho-spoon-text-file-output-additional-information-header Regards, Luis